# R function to strip dataframe into individual columns poly

Tags: r

I need to update my code in order to make it more dynamic.

My dataframe can sometime contain 6 variables and sometime contain 9 variables. I need to create a dataframe based on the variables in question containing all of the different variables and the corresponding second order variables.

My code used to look like this

```
df3 <- data.frame(poly(test$hub, test$vacations, test$slot, test$income, test$market_size, test$average_distance_m, degree = 2, raw = TRUE))
df6 <- data.frame(poly(test$hub, test$vacations, test$slot, test$income, test$market_size, test$average_distance_m, test$noise1, test$noise2, test$noise3, degree = 2, raw = TRUE))
```

I was wondering if there was any way to make this more dynamic.
I tried

```
df <- data.frame(poly(test, degree = 2, raw = TRUE))
```

where test would update but I keep getting a error in FUN(X, Y, ...) : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Comment: does passing a mtrix work i,e. `poly(as.matrix(mtcars[1:3]), raw=TRUE, degree=2)`

Comment: That works! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you convert your data to a matrix then your final attempt would work.

For example,

```
# typing all variables in manually
original = with(mtcars, poly(mpg, cyl, disp, hp, drat, wt, degree=2, raw=TRUE))
#OR
# convert dataframe to matrix and apply poly (lazily using indices instead of names)
using_matrix = poly(as.matrix(mtcars[1:6]), degree=2, raw=TRUE)

all.equal(original, using_matrix, check.attributes=FALSE)
# TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `do.call`

```
  my_funct = function(dat) do.call(poly,c(unname(dat),raw=TRUE,degree=2))
  (df_2vars <- my_funct(iris[1:2]))
  (df_4vars <- my_funct(iris[1:4]))
```